# Lost cert for published app

Tags: android, google-play

I have a free app published in Android market.  I have lost the certificate used to sign the current version but I want to publish an updated version. Android market refuses to accept my upgrade because it is signed by a new certificate. I realize the users will have to uninstall the current version to get the upgrade but it's not clear how to get the updated version into the market so that the current users will find it.

What are my options?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only option is to change the description for your old app that would point to your new app and hope that existing users will notice it.

Comment: So add the upgrade as a new app, which means give it a new package but can have the same app name and a newer version number. Then update the older (now obsolete) app's description to point to the new app and maybe indicate an uninstall will be needed.